# Unable to Understand Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I had an assignment on dynamic programming due last night, but I had to turn it in unfinished because i could not understand how to solve the last problem:

> The state wants to monitor traffic on a highway n miles long. It costs c<sub>i</sub> to install a monitoring device on mile i of the highway. The maximum distance between monitoring devices should not be more than d miles. That is, if there is a monitoring device on mile i, then there must be one monitoring device from mile i + 1 to mile i + d (or it is the case that i + d > n). The state wants a plan that will minimize the cost. Assume there is an array C[1..n] of costs.
>
> Let v<sub>k</sub> be the cost of the best solution assuming a k mile highway and assuming a monitoring device on mile k. Given C and d, if the values of v<sub>1</sub> through v<sub>k-1</sub> are known, show how to determine the value of v<sub>k</sub>. You can write this mathematically, or provide pseudocode in the style of the book. Note you need to take into account all possible values of k from k = 1 to k = n.

I'm sure a problem similar to this will appear on the exam coming up and I'd like to at least know where to begin solving this, so any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: I'm not asking for anyone to write code for me, I'm asking for anyone to help me understand how I would solve this.

Comment: The answer is still too broad, consisting of four questions wrapped into one which would also involve opinionated answers, both of which are not allowed on SO. You should ask these, one at a time, on programmers.stackexchange

Comment: Okay, thank you for the constructive advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define DP[i] as the minimum cost of installing a monitor at station i and some other indexes which are less than i (such that each consecutive station is less than or equal to distance d)

Now the answer to our problem would be

min(DP[n - d + 1], ...DP[n - 2], DP[n - 1], DP[n])

That is the minimum cost of having the last monitor on last d indexes.

Now, the recurrence relation for the dynamic programming can be easily seen as :

DP[i] = min(DP[i - 1], DP[i - 2], ... DP[i - d]) + C[i]
If we want to install a monitor on ith index, we install it by cost C[i], and we must also ensure that we have a monitor in previous d indexes. So, we take the minimum of installing the second last monitor on it's previous d indexes.

If you code the recurrence by naive method it looks O(n * d), but by using the sliding window minimum algorithm using a doubly ended queue, you can reduce the time complexity to asymptotically O(n).

As this is an assignment problem, I won't write in detail. You should be able to follow up from this point.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that helps put it in perspective.